# Adding enough sets to get a model of ZF

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Working in (first or second-order) ZF, suppose we started with an arbitrary set $A$ containing $\omega$ and wanted to add enough things to $A$ to get a model, not necessarily minimal, of (first or second-order) ZF. Is there anything wrong with the following brute force approach?

$T_0 = A$

$T_{\alpha+1} = trcl(T_{\alpha}) \cup\hspace{2mm} \{f[X]\hspace{1.5mm} |\hspace{2mm} X \in T_{\alpha} ,f:X \rightarrow V  \} \cup \{ \cup(x) \hspace{1.5mm} |\hspace{2mm} x \in T_{\alpha}\} \cup  \{ \wp(x) \hspace{1.5mm} |\hspace{2mm} x \in T_{\alpha}\}$

$T_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} T_\beta$ for $\alpha$ limit.

Let $T = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \textrm{ORD}} T_{\alpha}$

---

Then $T \models$ ZF.

Proof: $T$ is transitive, and that suffices for $T$ to model Extensionality and Foundation.

$T$ models Replacement because whenever $X \in T$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $X \in T_{\alpha}$. So given $f: X \rightarrow V$, then $rng(f) \in T_{\alpha+1} \subset T$.

$T$ models Powerset because whenever $x \in T$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $x \in T_{\alpha}$, and then $\wp(x) \in T_{\alpha+1} \subset T$.

$T$ models Union because whenever $x \in T$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $x \in T_{\alpha}$, and then $\cup(x) \in T_{\alpha+1} \subset T$.

$T$ models Infinity by assumption that $\omega \in A$.

Separation and Pairing should follow from Replacement (and Powerset in the case of Pairing).

Comment: Are you familiar with the  Lowenheim-Skolem process?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, but I'm really looking for a model of second order ZF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this "works" in that it gives you a (class) model of ZF, but it just gives you the entire universe $V$.  Indeed, as soon as $T_\alpha$ contains a nonempty set, $T_{\alpha+1}$ will contain every singleton set, since every singleton is the image of some function on any nonempty set.  Then taking unions will give that $T_{\alpha+2}$ is all of $V$.

However, it is not necessary to consider arbitrary functions as you have done.  Instead of functions $f:X\to V$, you can consider just functions $f:X\to T_\alpha$.  Then your construction still works (since any function from a set to $T$ will have image contained in some $T_\alpha$), and if you start with a set $A$ of rank $\alpha$, it is not too hard to show that your model $T$ will be $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible cardinal greater than $\alpha$, or all of $V$ if no such $\kappa$ exists.  Indeed, your construction is basically constructing the smallest [Grothendieck universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) containing $A$.

Comment: If I want to use the construction to show that the least inaccessible $\kappa$ greater than $\alpha$ exists (i.e. $\kappa$ = the height of T), will it work to index the union of the $T_{\alpha}$'s by the set of inaccessibles instead of $ORD$?

Comment: No...you need successor ordinals.  And in any case, you certainly can't prove that $\kappa$ exists, because it might not.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how you propose that the construction would work if you only use the inaccessibles.  For instance, what if there is only one inaccessible?  What if there are none?

Comment: No, that would give $T$ a height of just $\lambda$, which is totally different from the $\lambda$th inaccessible.